# Change content of a DialogFragment from a Recyclerview Adapter

Tags: android

I'm not quite sure if this is possible, but I'm trying to change the content of a custom DialogFragment (read: content as in 1 imageview, and 3 textviews) inside of a Recyclerview adapter.

My current custom DialogFragment:

```
public class ServiceDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.service_card, container, false);
    }
}
```

And the layout: 
[image]

As you see in the image above: I have a list behind the where the DialogFragment is displayed and whenever I press one of those "buttons" that DialogFragment appears. **But my question is**: how do I change the content of the custom DialogFragment inside of my Recyclerview Adapter?

My adapter:

```
public class ServiceAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ServiceAdapter.ViewHolder>{
    private final String TAG = "******* Service Adapter";
    private ArrayList<ServiceObject> mDataset;
    private Context mContext;
    private Resources mResources;
    private Context location;

    public ServiceAdapter(ArrayList<ServiceObject> mDataset, Context mContext, Resources mResources) {
        this.mDataset   = mDataset;
        this.mContext   = mContext;
        this.mResources = mResources;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        location = parent.getContext();
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.service_box, parent, false);

        return new ViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.title.setText(mDataset.get(position).getTitle());
        holder.icon.setImageResource(mResources.getIdentifier(Integer.toString(mDataset.get(position).getIcon()), "drawable", "net.example.adapter"));
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mDataset == null ? 0 : mDataset.size();
    }


    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{

        TextView title, desc, price;
        ImageView icon;

        public ViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            title   = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.service_box_title);
            price   = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.service_card_price);
            icon    = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.service_box_icon);
            v.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            FragmentActivity activity = (FragmentActivity)(mContext);
            FragmentManager fm = activity.getSupportFragmentManager();
            ServiceDialogFragment alertDialog = new ServiceDialogFragment();
            alertDialog.show(fm, "display_service");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you display the dialog fragment. post some code

Comment: You can pass some data to your dialog frament and use that to change what you want. Info @ http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html

Comment: So make a method inside of the dialog fragment which changes the content?

Comment: See the link in the previous comment. check setArguments and getArguments

Comment: Nice, I will try it out now. I'll give you a report on it in a bit.

Comment: Thank you very much man! It worked!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @raghunandan, I figured it out. Resource: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html

Comment: You should probably post what you have done instead of posting a link to the docs